# Building $S^k$ as a cell inductively

Tags: algebraic-topology

So I was reading Hatcher, and I stumbled upon the following sentence: "We can give $S^n$ a cell structure in which each of the subspheres $S^k$ is a subcomplex, by regarding $S^k$ as being obtained inductively from the equatorial $S^{k-1}$ by attaching two $k$-cells, the components of $S^k-S^{k-1}$"

So I am confused on the construction. Say we have $S^{k-1}$, then we have to $k$-cells, which are just the interior of $D^k$, then I have this two interiors, and I attach them to where? He says $S^k-S^{k-1}$ which seems inappropriate because one shouldn't use $S^k$ in the construction of $S^k$.

If someone could clarify this and perhaps show how to build $S^2$ from $S^1$ in concrete I would appreciate it.

What I think he means is that we take $2$ $k$-cells, and define the attaching map to glue the boundary of $D^k=S^{k-1}$ to $S^{k-1}$ by the identity map. For the case $n=2$ would it be just take two open circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and join the circles by only their boundaries, but there is emptiness inside, so we get a $S^2$?

Comment: In the passage you quoted, Hatcher doesn't say to attach two $k$-cells *to* the components of $S^k-S^{k-1}$.  He says to attach two $k$-cells, which *are* the components of $S^k-S^{k-1}$.

Comment: In page $7$ he literally says "by attaching two $k$-cells, the components of $S^k-S^{k-1}$".

Comment: @AndreasBlass yeah but I get it now. I must have an old version or something because I found that sentence confusing, but the answer given by Henry makes sense.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm referring to. The comma indicates an apposition; it is does not mean "to".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh! that makes sense. English is not my native language so I was thrown off by that comma. I thought commas are only allowed after "for, and, not, but, or, yet, so" (the so called FANBOYS of commas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that you are attaching hemispheres via the identity map.

To get $S^2$ from $S^1$, you attach two copies of $D^2$ to $S^1$ via the identity map $\partial D^2 \longrightarrow S^1$. One of the $D^2$'s is the "northern" hemisphere and the other $D^2$ is the "southern" hemisphere.

For arbitrary $n$ you do the same thing: Attach two copies of $D^n$ to $S^{n-1}$ to obtain $S^n$. Here we assume $S^{n-1}$ has been obtained from $S^{n-2}$ by attaching two hemispheres, and so on. This is how the inductive cell structure is obtained.

Starting from the bottom up: Attach two copies of $D^1$ to $S^0$ to get $S^1$, two copies of $D^2$ to $S^1$ to get $S^2$, and continue attaching two disks of the appropriate dimension until you get $S^n$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Hatcher wrote it in a very weird way, thanks!